# Exit a loop with a method parameter

Tags: c#, loops, methods

I'm coding a method to repeat an action, via a while loop, until the parameter of the method is at true.

The method GetStatus communicate with a robotic arm to get different status.
Instead of writing always the same code(which work, I tested it), I'm would like to use a method which will take into consideration the state of the method parameter at each lap of the loop.

I thought using ref could be the solution but I can't use it because the method parameter will be a parameter from my class.

```
public Class MyClass
{
    public bool Param1 { get; set; }

    public void GetStatus()
    {
        Param1 = true;
    }

    private void WaitDone(bool waitingVal, int timeout)
    {
        Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
        timer.Start();
        do
        {
            GetStatus();

        } while (!(timer.ElapsedMilliseconds >= timeout || waitingVal));
        timer.Stop();
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        WaitDone(Param1, 3000);
    }
}
```

My loop ends only thanks to the timeout, but if the state of the parameter of the method change, it won't be taken into consideration inside the loop.

Thanks and sorry for my English.

Comment: When/how do you expect the `waitingVal` to change?

Comment: If I understood your problem correctly, you should check out CancellationTokenSource for that behavior. You'll be able to pass a cancellation token to your method (as a parameter), then between each loop, check if the cancellationToken has been flagged as Cancelled or not. That cancellation can be done by any other class in your project that has a handle on the object you provided as a paramter.

Comment: The waitingVal will change when a parameter updated by GetStatus will see his state changed.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can exit a loop when the condition used in the loop changes.
2. Make sure you change the condition within the loop.

In your code you are calling `GetStatus()` which changes `Param1` and not `waitingVal`. Make sure you change the right variable. If you decide to change `Param1` within the loop. You should use the same variable for checking the while condition. Hope I made it clear.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for correcting my post. =)

I just created the method get status like that to change the Param1. Though GetStatus will change much more parameter state and I can't use them directly for the loop. I could directly write this code every time I need it, but I prefer to use a method.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to your problem?

Comment: Yes, my company already have a method to deal with my case, but since I'm new I don't know all the library they have developed.
So I don't have a proper way ^^